# Elmah MVC how handle error and show Error page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, elmah, elmah.mvc

In asp mvc 5 i have installed Elmah.MVC (2.1.2) with NuGet.

Now in a Action method i've raise an exception:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        throw new Exception("This is test Exception");
        return View();
    }
}
```

I can succesfull view the log in

```
http://localhost:49353/elmah
```

But how can i handle the error? How can i show the Error page inside the Shared Folder? Now i see the Exception not handled page in the browser

Comment: Usually, it will appear in production, where the host is different from Localhost. Take a look at your web.config, in the customErros tag.

Comment: You can log an exception without throwing it, using `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex, HttpContext.Current);`

Comment: @FabioLuz u're right. Now where is defined the default page? It's show the /Shared/Error.cshtml...but if i want change the called default page?

Comment: @Tom just set the `Default Redirect`. Take a look at the docs https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx